# How do I upload multiple files using Kivy (on android)?

Tags: android, python, file-upload, kivy

I've got a Kivy app that does what I need it to, with one problem. I have an event handler button that does this:

```
def upload_files(self):
    s = requests.Session()
    while self.selected_files:
        filename = self.selected_files.pop()
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            s.post('http://example.com/upload', files={'file': f})
        self.upload_queue.item_strings = [os.path.basename(_) for _ in self.selected_files]
```

This uploads the file a-OK. However, when this runs on my Android it completely locks up the system. Is there a correct way of uploading files with Kivy? Searching for `python kivy file upload` didn't turn up anything useful. The closest thing I've found was https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html but it doesn't show how to upload a file. Is there an example somewhere for uploading files in Kivy without blocking on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Do your blocking operation in a thread.

Comment: Care to elaborate?